# Given metric spaces $X$ and $Y$, does there exist a metric space containing isometric copies of both $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces. Does there exist a metric space $Z$ such that both $X$ and $Y$ can be isometrically embedded into $Z$?

It is easy to see that the answer is positive if $X$ and $Y$ are bounded (consider the disjoint union of the two spaces). But what happens when $X$ or $Y$ is unbounded?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is going wrong for you with the disjoint union of unbounded spaces?

Comment: I don't know how to define a metric on the disjoint union so that the triangle inequality holds. When the spaces are bounded we can define the distance from any point of X to any point of Y to be constant, but this won't work anymore if at least one of the spaces is unbounded.

Comment: With a disjoint union of two metric spaces, how do you define the distance between a point in one space and a point in the other? Obviously in some cases there's more than one way to do it, but how do you show that in every cases there's at least one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint. Choose a point $x_0\in X$ and a point $y_0\in Y$. For $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ define
$$d(x,y)=d_X(x,x_0)+1+d_Y(y_0,y).$$